# Retrieve Datas from a Table into a Select tag

Tags: html, forms, phpmyadmin

How can I access datas(workers' name) from a column of table(Workers' Info) that is stored in a database and use those datas(workers' names) as a list of workers in a HTML Form using Select tag ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an application server of some kind - ColdFusion, PHP, Node, etc.